# Watchman keep crashing when I developing react-native

Tags: node.js, react-native, watchman

1. OS:macOS 10.12.6
2. `node -v` 6.9.0 `npm -v` 3.10.8
3. `watchman -v` 4.9.0 installed via brew
4. `create-react-native-app --version`:1.0.

As I found, watchman fails to work after I change  several files, although it works perfectly if nothing changed. Then I tried
`watchman watch-del-all && watchman shutdown-server && npm start --reset-cache`.
It just crashes.

[image]

Anyone can help out of this? Googled for several solutions,but it just cannot work? Tell me if any other information is in need.